# how to focus on picker in codenameone

Tags: focus, textfield, codenameone

In codenameone I have a form in which 3 textfield and 1 datepicker.
1.textfield
2.datepicker
3.textfield
4. textfield
When I click on the 3textfield , keyboard is displayed and there is next button and when I click on next button ,it moves to 4 textfield

But when I click on the 1 textfield keyboard is displayed without next button (with done button) and when I click on the done ,it doesnot move to datepicker so I have added nextFoucus/down/right on 1 textfield  to move the picker but it stays on 1 textfield when done is clicked

So how to move datepicker from 1 textfield when click on keyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

Focus is designed for non-touch devices. The picker is currently on a part of the next/done cycle on the device.

Changing this should be done deep in the Codename One native code and its not trivial. You can file an RFE in the Codename One issue tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/codenameone/issues).